# VSTS Testing Angular with npm task

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I have a build pipeline in VSTS that works, which contains the following steps

1. .NET Core Restore
2. .NET Core Build
3. .NET Core Test
4. Publish Test Results
5. .Net Core Publish

Now I want to add a couple of additional steps to run the npm (Angular) tests.  I have a package.json that defines all of the typical commands, including test and test-single-run.  It has references to jasmine-core, karma, etc.  I can post full files if someone wants to see them.  From the command line on my machine I can run the npm run test-single-run command and it works and executes the tests as expected.

I added 3 steps to the build pipeline above after step 4, 2 npm steps and another Publish Test Results (don't know if/how this works with 2 different sources, but that is not my problem right now).

The first npm step runs the command install and has the Working folder with package.json as src/Cranalytics.
The second npm step runs custom with the command line arguments of run test-single-run and also has the same Working folder specified.

The first npm command runs without any errors and I can see it pull down a bunch of stuff.  The second one errors with the following:

```
    C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" run test-single-run"  
    > Cranalytics@1.0.0 test-single-run d:\a\1\s\src\Cranalytics
    > karma start wwwroot/karma.conf.js --single-run
    [33m07 07 2017 15:13:06.270:WARN [watcher]: [39mPattern "d:/a/1/s/src/Cranalytics/wwwroot/lib/ngInfiniteScroll/build/ng-infinite-scroll.min.js" does not match any file.
    [32m07 07 2017 15:13:06.759:INFO [karma]: [39mKarma v1.7.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
    [32m07 07 2017 15:13:06.760:INFO [launcher]: [39mLaunching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
    [32m07 07 2017 15:13:06.769:INFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser Chrome
    [33m07 07 2017 15:14:06.773:WARN [launcher]: [39mChrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
    [33m07 07 2017 15:14:08.777:WARN [launcher]: [39mChrome was not killed in 2000 ms, sending SIGKILL.
    [33m07 07 2017 15:14:10.778:WARN [launcher]: [39mChrome was not killed by SIGKILL in 2000 ms, continuing.
    npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
    npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "test-single-run"
    npm ERR! node v6.10.0
    npm ERR! npm v3.10.10
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! Cranalytics@1.0.0 test-single-run: `karma start wwwroot/karma.conf.js --single-run`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the Cranalytics@1.0.0 test-single-run script 'karma start wwwroot/karma.conf.js --single-run'.
    npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
    npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the Cranalytics package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR! karma start wwwroot/karma.conf.js --single-run
    npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    npm ERR! npm bugs Cranalytics
    npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    npm ERR! npm owner ls Cranalytics
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR! d:\a\1\s\src\Cranalytics\npm-debug.log
    Found npm debug log, make sure the path matches with the one in npm's output: d:\a\1\s\src\Cranalytics\npm-debug.log
    0 info it worked if it ends with ok
    1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
    1 verbose cli 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
    1 verbose cli 'run',
    1 verbose cli 'test-single-run' ]
    2 info using npm@3.10.10
    3 info using node@v6.10.0
    4 verbose run-script [ 'pretest-single-run',
    4 verbose run-script 'test-single-run',
    4 verbose run-script 'posttest-single-run' ]
    5 info lifecycle Cranalytics@1.0.0~pretest-single-run: Cranalytics@1.0.0
    6 silly lifecycle Cranalytics@1.0.0~pretest-single-run: no script for pretest-single-run, continuing
    7 info lifecycle Cranalytics@1.0.0~test-single-run: Cranalytics@1.0.0
    8 verbose lifecycle Cranalytics@1.0.0~test-single-run: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
    9 verbose lifecycle Cranalytics@1.0.0~test-single-run: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;d:\a\1\s\src\Cranalytics\node_modules\.bin;C:\LR\mms\Services\Mms\Provisioner\TaskAgent\agents\2.119.1\externals\git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft
     MPI\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program
     Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Xoreax\IncrediBuild;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program
Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Program Files\Docker;C:\NPM\Modules;;C:\Program Files\Git LFS;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\java\ant\apache-ant-1.9.7\bin;C:\java\mav...
    10 verbose lifecycle Cranalytics@1.0.0~test-single-run: CWD: d:\a\1\s\src\Cranalytics
    11 silly lifecycle Cranalytics@1.0.0~test-single-run: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'karma start wwwroot/karma.conf.js --single-run' ]
    12 silly lifecycle Cranalytics@1.0.0~test-single-run: Returned: code: 1 signal: null
    13 info lifecycle Cranalytics@1.0.0~test-single-run: Failed to exec test-single-run script
    14 verbose stack Error: Cranalytics@1.0.0 test-single-run: `karma start wwwroot/karma.conf.js --single-run`
    14 verbose stack Exit status 1
    14 verbose stack at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)
    14 verbose stack at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    14 verbose stack at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
    14 verbose stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
    14 verbose stack at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    14 verbose stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    14 verbose stack at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    14 verbose stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
    15 verbose pkgid Cranalytics@1.0.0
    16 verbose cwd d:\a\1\s\src\Cranalytics
    17 error Windows_NT 10.0.14393
    18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "test-single-run"
    19 error node v6.10.0
    20 error npm v3.10.10
    21 error code ELIFECYCLE
    22 error Cranalytics@1.0.0 test-single-run: `karma start wwwroot/karma.conf.js --single-run`
    22 error Exit status 1
    23 error Failed at the Cranalytics@1.0.0 test-single-run script 'karma start wwwroot/karma.conf.js --single-run'.
    23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
    23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the Cranalytics package,
    23 error not with npm itself.
    23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    23 error karma start wwwroot/karma.conf.js --single-run
    23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    23 error npm bugs Cranalytics
    23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    23 error npm owner ls Cranalytics
    23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
    24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

    Error: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd failed with return code: 1
```

After switching it to run on a Local Agent that has VS2017 installed on it I get the following errors in the Restore step

```
2017-07-12T13:21:01.1976623Z [command]C:\dbagent\bin\dotnet.exe restore C:\dbagent\_work\2\s\Cranalytics.Tests\Cranalytics.Tests.csproj
2017-07-12T13:21:01.2757797Z ##[error]Unable to process command '##vso[task.complete ]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code: 2147516564.' successfully. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2017-07-12T13:21:01.2757797Z ##[error]Command doesn't have valid result value.
2017-07-12T13:21:01.3695338Z [command]C:\dbagent\bin\dotnet.exe restore C:\dbagent\_work\2\s\src\Cranalytics\Cranalytics.csproj
2017-07-12T13:21:01.3695338Z ##[error]Unable to process command '##vso[task.complete ]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code: 2147516564.' successfully. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2017-07-12T13:21:01.3695338Z ##[error]Command doesn't have valid result value.
```

System Path:
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;%USERPROFILE%.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t run karma jasmine test on Hosted agent. You need to setup a private build agent.

Refer to this article to set up a private build agent, it’s easy: [Deploy an agent on Windows](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows)

Comment: there is no way to run JS tests in the hosted agent?

Comment: @PaulCavacas It is the karma jasmine test that need to interactive with browser, the private build agent is required. If it is just the unit test for JS, you can run it in the hosted agent.

Comment: I have a private agent setup and just installed VS2017 onto that box.  I then tries to queue the build into that private agent (the current build without the Karma tests) and I get an error when it runs the command dotnet.exe restore pointing to the csproj file.  Do you know what else I need to do to get this work?

Comment: @PaulCavacas What's the detail error message? You need to install [.net core SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core)

Comment: I have installed VS 2017 already.  And just to be certain I installed the SDK from the link above and it was already installed (said Repair/Uninstall in the install).  I have added the error message to the question above

Comment: @PaulCavacas Could you call dotnet restore command to restore packages manually on your build agent machine? What's the version of core SDK? (run dotnet --version to check version)

Comment: dotnet --version returns 1.0.4.  Not sure why it doesn't say 1.1 I've installed the latest version from the site.  When I run the command C:\dbagent\bin\dotnet.exe restore C:\dbagent\_work\2\s\Cranalytics.Tests\Cranalytics.Tests.csproj nothing it returned.  It immediately returns with no message.  If I run the command dotnet.exe restore C:\dbagent\_work\2\s\Cranalytics.Tests\Cranalytics.Tests.csproj from a .NET Command Prompt then it works and I see it restore all of the dependencies.

Comment: @PaulCavacas What's your OS? You can download Windows (x64) Installer SDK (not runtime) if it is windows 64 bit. Try to download .Net core SDK again and reinstall it. After that restart the machine and check version.

Comment: Sorry I've been away.  The OS is Windows Server 2012R2.  I'm not sure what you want me to download.  When I search for that I get Windows 10 SDK, is that what you want installed.  I did restart the machine and had no difference

Comment: @PaulCavacas Check this screenshot: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AresBGZVYryjhTKRaO1iCyHbO5ym

Comment: That is what I downloaded

Comment: @PaulCavacas Try to check system environment variable (path key), on the other hand, try to uninstall all .NET Core SDK, then install latest Core SDK and check the result.

Comment: No changes.
The path is in the original question

Comment: @PaulCavacas Do you have another machine? If so, try to setup the build agent on that machine.

Comment: I found that problem.  This build was still using the Preview tasks for the various .NET commands.  As soon as I switch this from the 0.* version to the 1.* versions it got past that part of the build.  Now it is getting to the npm step and failing.  It is failing because the postinstall command says bower install.  Once I got this I went on to the server and did npm -g bower install and then when I run the command on the server I get no errors, but when it runs from the build I still get 'bower' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: OK.  I got around the bower issue, by moving everything to npm and just removing the bower command.  Thanks for all of your help.